# How to change store based on country location in Magento244?

Tags: magento2.4, multistore, store-view, geoip

In magento2 how to change store according to country using geoip location..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an event in:

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
    <event name='controller_action_predispatch'>
        <observer name='store_redirect_location_based' instance='Vendor\Module\Observer\Redirect' />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create a php class:

> Vendor/Module/Observer/Redirect.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Redirect implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $curl;

    protected $session;

    protected $remoteAddress;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Curl $curl,
        SessionManagerInterface $session,
        RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
        
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->curl = $curl;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectStore = $this->session->getCustomRedirection();
        if(!($redirectStore)){
            $visitorIp = $this->getVisitorIp();
            $baseUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
            $apiUrl = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$visitorIp;
            $this->curl->get($apiUrl);
            $response = json_decode($this->curl->getBody(), true);
            $countryCode = $response['geoplugin_countryCode'];
            if($countryCode == 'IN'){
                $redirectionUrl = $baseUrl."stores/store/redirect/?___store=english_in"; 
                $this->session->setCustomRedirection(true);  
                $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getVisitorIp()
    {
        $remoteAddress = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
        return $remoteAddress;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for  given answer